# Using Observable to filter data

Tags: typescript, observable

I have an array of objects that I would like to filter. I thought using Observables would be a good idea. Is this correct?

```
export class MyClass
{
    public item1: string;
    public item2: string;
}

let myArray = MyClass[];

myArray.push({ item1: 'foo1', item2: 'bar1'})
myArray.push({ item1: 'foo2', item2: 'bar2'})

Observable.of(myArray)
    .map(data => data.item1)  
    .subscrite(data => <<here there should be a list of strings here: ['foo1', 'foo2']>>)
```

What am I missing? And is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Observable.of(array)` you'll get a stream with one entry containing the whole array. Then the `map` will result in undefined and nothing is emitted.

This example will work because it creates a stream with two elements:

```
const o1 = { item1: 'foo1', item2: 'bar1'};
const o2 = { item1: 'foo2',  item2: 'bar2'};
Observable.of(o1, o2)
  .map(data => data.item1)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

I created a simple example showing this here: https://plnkr.co/edit/1fqjGwGtUZKv0jDGuOkA

For an array you could use the spread operator to map the array to multiple arguments:

```
Observable.of(...myArray)
  .map(data => data.item1)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```